# ERROR ITMS-90096: "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5"

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I am trying to upload my iPhone app as a new version and getting the following error message when upload the IPA file in to the 'Loader' Application...

App was developed in Xcode 6 using swift...

[image]

I have defined "App Icons and Launch Image" section settings as follows

[image]

Idea is to Use storyboard "Initial View Controller" as the "Launch Screen"...

Would be grateful if anyone can guide me in getting this done. Thanks..

Comment: Is your deployment target iOS 7 or earlier? If so, you need to add launch images too. The launch screen is only for iOS 8 and later.

Comment: Not sure you can use a XIB with connections as Lauchscreen but I am not familiar with storyboards. @maddy remarks is correct though

Comment: Hi rmaddy thanks. Yes the development target is 7.1. So can't I use the storyboatrd's 'initial viewcontroller' as the launch screen in this case then?

Comment: I developed using xcode 6 with storyboard for UIs. Is it I have to keep the existing behaviour (storyboard launch screen file) for ios 8 and above AND also launch images for earlier versions than 8. I mean both storyboard launch screen and Launch Images in this case

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error.

1.I created a new storyboard file as LaunchScreen.

2.Target  of my project -> App Icon and Launch Images -> Change the          Launch Screen File to the newly created LaunchScreen storyboard.

3.Save, Build and Archived

This thing worked for me.Hope this helps you to.

Answer (score 0):

LaunchScreen is only suppored from iOS8 upwards, so if you want to target iOS7 as well you need to specify the various launch images in their correct dimensions.

Specifically for this very error, ensure that you populate the image catalog for all the Portrait iPhone options in all the iOS versions that you want to support.

[image]